# how to write hstore column in where clause of spring data jpa query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, where-clause, hibernate, hstore

I am facing a problem in writing the "hstore" type column in where clause of spring data jpa query.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
@Query(
value = "select ld from LocationData ld inner join fetch ld.assetData ad where ld.assetId in (:assetIds) and ld.orgId = :orgId and ld.eventTimestamp between  :startDate and :endDate and ad.source in (:source) and 
            ad.attr -> 'CorrelationId' is not null",

countQuery = "select count(ld) from LocationData ld inner join ld.assetData ad where ld.assetId in (:assetIds) and ld.orgId = :orgId and ld.eventTimestamp between  :startDate and :endDate and ad.source in (:source) and ad.attr -> 'CorrelationId' is not null""

)

Page<LocationData> findByAssetIdInAndOrgIdAndEventTimestampBetween(@Param("assetIds") List<Long> assetIds,
                                                                       @Param("orgId") Integer orgId,
                                                                       @Param("startDate") Long startEventTimestamp,
                                                                       @Param("endDate") Long endEventTimeStamp,
                                                                       @Param("source") List<String> source,
                                                                       Pageable pageable);
```

In the above query "attr" is a hstore type column. I have a key by name CorrelationId in attr column. I want to select to those where CorrelationId key is not null. I tried with "ad.attr -> 'CorrelationId' is not null" in pgAdmin it is working pretty fine but in spring data jpa query it is not working and throwing error as invalid identifier.

Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: **FIRST** - forget about Spring, Hibernate, Java or (`insert_your_cool_development_environment_here`). Use the `psql` CLI (or GUI tool of your choice) to run the raw query - then put that into your IDE/Framework! If the query works in `psql` but not in spring, then it's an IDE issue. If not, bring the query back to dba.stackexchange, stripped of the Java code! Voting to close until new information is added!

Answer (score 0):

If JPA doesn't like the "->" operator, you can try the functional forms

```
fetchval(ad.attr,'CorrelationId') IS NOT NULL
```

or

```
defined(ad.attr,'CorrelationId')
```